# MobArena: PVPing in lobby

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

Is it possible to stop PVP in the lobby and spectator regions in the mob arena? I am using version 0.96.6. People can somehow PVP in the lobby and spectator regions. How can I stop PVPin those regions?

Comment: I've never really used MobArena, but you could use Factions or WorldGuard to set a boundary to stop PvP. I would recommend WorldGuard instead of Factions, though.

Answer (score -1):

Download **WorldGuard**, create a region ([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvmO5mchNF4/)) and type command : **/rg flag  pvp deny**

Comment: Please summarize the tutorial here, so that your answer can help someone without needing to follow a link elsewhere.  It also ensures that your answer is still valid in case that link goes down.